# Why is the function to find factorial wrong?

Tags: c, math, combinations

My function to compute the factorial of n isn't working. None of the print statements are executed, even though they test for all possible values of n.

What am I doing wrong?

```
long int factorial(int n) //function to find factorial
{
    int i=1;
    long int p=1;
    if(n=0)
    {
        printf("1");
    }
    if(n>0)
    {
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
        p *=i;
       }
       printf("%ld",p);
    }
    if(n<0)
    {
        printf("Error");
    }
}
```

I also tried to do

```
p = p*i; //instead of p *=i;
```

which also doesn't seem to work.
I can't pinpoint where my mistake is.

Comment: Instead of returning a number, you're printing a number and not return anything.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is comparison.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What really happens? Just saying there's something "wrong" doesn't tell us much. Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [mcve] to show us, with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: Close-voters: how is this off-topic? The use and distinction of `=` vs. `==` is very much on-topic for [c]

Answer (score 5):

In line 5, you overwrite the requested value of n with 0.

That then evaluates to zero (false), and the next two conditionals are also rendered false, so nothing prints.

Use `if (n==0)` instead.

As an additional note: your function is declared to return a long int, but you don't actually return anything explicitly.